# How to call R when multiple versions are installed?

Tags: 16.04, r

I have installed R-3.4.2 and R-3.6.1 on the same machines per instructions given [here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/215488098-Installing-multiple-versions-of-R). How do I open an R session? I mostly use R on terminal and not the Rstudio GUI.